# Need to write OHLC data of stocks real time in a file and read it using another code simultaneously

Tags: c#, csv, file-handling, csvhelper

I am using CsvHelper library in C# to write OHLC Data of stocks real-time in a csv file. Everything is working fine but when I am opening the file to see the data it is giving me an exception stating "The Process cannot access the file 'FileLocation'". Is there a way to write it without getting this exception and after each new entry I can read the same using some other program running independently from this one?

Comment: Did you use `using` to close the file properly?

Comment: Yeah I did that

Comment: You may need to give write access only to the account that is writing to the file and give read only access to all other accounts.  The main issue is that the process that is reading the file will need to open the file ReadOnly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4964737/2355006

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the file read-only. Turn read-only off just before you write to the file and then immediately set the file back to read-only after writing.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var records = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
    };

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false
    };
    
    string filePath = @"c:\Temp\myfile.csv";
    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

    fInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
    
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(records);
    }

    fInfo.IsReadOnly = true;
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure if you read the file, that you open the file with `FileAccess` set to `FileAccess.Read` and `FileShare` set to `FileShare.ReadWrite`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    string filePath = @"c:\Temp\myfile.csv";
    var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();
        
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            var record = csv.GetRecord<Foo>();
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```